# How do I use a vue.js nested for loop over two arrays with a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

*This was resolved and my parent view and child component code are now correct and functioning*  Using Vue.js, I'm attempting to iterate analogous to a nested for loop to render a matrix table display.  To achieve this I'm attempting to use a nested v-for loop but couldn't get it to work originally.

The data I'm using to build the table exists as a schedule of dates, each coming from a schedule collection in MongoDB.  For each given day all the teams play a match against another team.  The match data for each team lives in a schedule array in each document.

To pare down the approach and accomplish this I've created a schedule table of all the teams' schedules in the parent view, and passed it off as a property to the child component to streamline the v-for coding.

The traditional pattern for what I'm attempting to do in the child component is logically:

```
for(const i=0; i<schedules.length; i++) {
for(const j=0; j<weeks.length; j++) {
  console.log("This match is " + schedule[i] + " on " + week[j])
```

On the child component I've tried the following two strategies to no avail:

1.) Wrapping a v-for in a div:

```
<div v-for="(schedule,j) in schedules" :key="j">
        <sui-table-cell v-for="(number, i) in weeks" :key="i">
        {{schedules[schedule][i].team}}
        </sui-table-cell>
</div>
```

2.) Wrapping a v-for in a template (this code doesn't compile):

```
<template v-for="schedule in schedules">
        <sui-table-cell v-for="(number, i) in weeks" :key="i">
        {{schedules[schedule][i].team}}
        </sui-table-cell>
</template>
```

The data should look like so (if you click on the image you can see where I cannot get this to iterate):

[Correct View Of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otUeM.png)

Parent view template.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="ui header center aligned">ACL</h1>
    <h4 class="ui header center aligned schedule">
      <em>CRIBBAGE SCHEDULE</em>
    </h4>
    <sui-table id="standings" class="celled table center aligned">
      <inner-table :weeks="totalWeeks" :allPlayers="allPlayers" />
    </sui-table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import TableForm from "./TableForm.vue";
import { api } from "../../../helpers/helpers.js";
export default {
  name: "schedule-header",
  components: { "inner-table": TableForm },
  data() {
    return {
      totalWeeks: [],
      allDates: [],
      allPlayers: []
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.totalWeeks = await api.getTotalWeeks();
    this.allDates = await api.getAllDates();
    this.allPlayers = await api.getTeams();
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
h4.schedule {
  color: brown;
}
</style>
```

Child Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <sui-table-header>
      <sui-table-row>
        <sui-table-header-cell></sui-table-header-cell>
        <sui-table-header-cell>TEAMS</sui-table-header-cell>
        <sui-table-header-cell v-for="(number, i) in weeks" :key="i">WK{{i+1}}</sui-table-header-cell>
      </sui-table-row>
      <sui-table-row>
        <sui-table-cell></sui-table-cell>
        <sui-table-cell></sui-table-cell>
        <sui-table-cell v-for="(number, i) in weeks" :key="i">{{ number.gameDate.substring(0,10) }}</sui-table-cell>
      </sui-table-row>
    </sui-table-header>
    <sui-table-row v-for="(player, i) in allPlayers" :key="i">
      <sui-table-cell>{{i+1}}</sui-table-cell>
      <sui-table-cell>{{ player.player1 }}&{{player.player2}}</sui-table-cell>
      <sui-table-cell v-for="(week, j) in weeks" :key="j">{{player.schedule[j]}}</sui-table-cell>
    </sui-table-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["weeks", "allPlayers"]
};
</script>
```

Comment: `{{schedule[i].team}}` or `{{schedules[j][i].team}}` should work

Comment: it would be a bit more helpful if you shared a snippet of what was in `schedules` and `weeks`

Comment: Appreciate your feedback.  I've gone ahead and sent a snippet of that data to the images above.  Essentially they are both arrays, weeks is an array of 10 dates.  Schedules is a table containing rows for each team's matches on a given date.

Comment: I agree that schedules[j][i].team should work.  I cannot get this to iterate however.  The template option just repeats everything in one cell.

Answer (score 1):

Vue uses **key** property to differ between components and prevent unnecessary rendering. So from your code `:key="i"`, Vue understands that all `sui-table-cell` with key `i` are the same. That's why you've got repeats. You should provide **unique** keys to avoid this.

This code would do, however I would not recommend to use index as a key and provide some better keying strategy.

```
<sui-table-row v-for="(player, i) in allPlayers" :key="i">
      <sui-table-cell>{{i+1}}</sui-table-cell>
      <sui-table-cell>{{ player.player1 }}&{{player.player2}}</sui-table-cell>
      <div v-for="(schedule,j) in schedules" :key="j">
        <sui-table-cell v-for="(number, i) in weeks" :key="`${j}_${i}`">
          {{schedules[j][i]}}
        </sui-table-cell>
      </div>
</sui-table-row>
```

Sample data:

```
{
    schedules: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]]
    weeks: [1/1,1/7,1/14,1/21,1/28,2/5,2/12,2/19,2/25,3/3]
}
```

The solution with template, will not really work, because `template` part is never rendered, it is used when you want to use `v-for`, for multiple internal elements such as:

```
<template v-for="...">
 <h1></h1>
 <p></p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  I popped that div in there and got the following error: 

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'team' of undefined"

I fiddled with it a bit to see if I could troubleshoot it and it wasn't readily apparent what is happening:

Comment: Fixed, try now `weeks[j].team`

Comment: Thanks again Alex, I tried it even though it looks exactly the same as what you told me to do previously:)  Same results...

Comment: Well, with some data it is better :) Try now

Comment: I changed the sample data to actually represent my data.  I've also modified my code that creates the schedules table to remove id, and just make it a simple array rather than an array of objects.  Now this renders more closely to what I need based on your input.  However, it puts all the data into the first column and repeats for all schedules into that column.  I've pasted a screenshot of what I'm talking about in my list of screenshots.  It's called "new screenshot".

Comment: Mind doing a codepen? You can start with this one https://codepen.io/alexbrohshtut/pen/oNXMYXz

Comment: I got one set up that illustrates what I'm attempting to do.  However, it does not have the stylesheet from semantic ui vue, nor the js.  Not sure how to add it.  The CDN links for the js and the css are at: <script src="https://unpkg.com/semantic-ui-vue/dist/semantic-ui-vue.min.js"></script> and <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css"
/>, respectively.  My pen is at: https://codepen.io/AdamFHelm/pen/zYGLoaB  
Note what happens when this code actually runs in the screenshot above in my initial outline, "new screenshot"

Comment: It is about semantic, try to do hard-coded html of whatever you need and then wrap it in v-for, I am not sure about how your inner table behave.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for helping yesterday! I figured out the problem.  I had too many v-for's originally and it was throwing things off.  I've updated the code above with the solution, and popped a picture in there so you can see how it looks.

Comment: Great to hear that you did it! :)